# Resolving a set of Observables (in Angular)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

For my application I have an Angular component. This component has a set of id's. For each id I want it to make an API Call (Observable) and when all API calls are finished, I want to run a function. So my component looks like this:

```
export class UploadFormFieldComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private readonly apiService: ApiService) {}

  @Input()
  documentIds: string[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.downloadFiles();
  }

  downloadFiles() {
    // iterate over documentIds and download file for each id
  }

  private downloadFile(id: string): Observable<{ id: string; name: string }> {
    return this.apiService.getFile(id);
  }

  finalFunction() {
    console.log('This function should run after each file is uploaded');
  }
}
```

The downloadFile function works fine. However I can't get the finalFunction to run after each downloadFile function has been excecuted. How to I shape my downloadFiles function?

Comment: I'd make use of recursion and invoke the downloadFile for each success in documentIds list and when its empty just quit out of the function. Good luck!

Comment: What have you tried? At first glance here, I'd tell you that it's to be expected that `finalFunction` is never called; nothing invokes it. However, I'm assuming you've tried some things that are meant to invoke it but just don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the array of ids to an array of observables that each download the specific item by id, then use [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) to create a single observable:

```js
  downloadFiles(): Observable<{ id: string; name: string }[]> {
    const downloads = this.documentIds.map(id => this.downloadFile(id));
    return forkJoin(downloads);
  }
```

Comment: To add to this and based on a comment that was made, do something like this over iteration or recursion. RxJS is a functional programming library, keep things functional if possible. And depending on how the iteration/recursion is handled, you may be sacrificing parallelism. Downloading files is highly parallelizable--to unparallelize is to slow down your app unnecessarily, let RxJS handle the parallelization heavy-lifting for you